# Spaceship java issue gui

Tags: java, swagger

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class LevelSelectionMouseListner extends MouseAdapter
{
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
  {
    int levelNum = -1;
    boolean standard = true;
    if(event.getSource() == levelMenu.getProvidedList())
{
  levelMenu.clearCustomList();
  levelNum = levelMenu.getProvidedLevelNum();
}
else if (event.getSource()==levelMenu.getCustomList())
{
  levelMenu.clearProvidedList();
  levelNum=levelMenu.getCustomLevelNum();
  standard = false;
}

if(event.getClickCount()==2)
{
  if (levelNum != -1)
  {
    changeContent(PLAY_PANEL, "startPlay");
    playMgr.initLevelForPlay(standard, levelNum);
    playPanel.startTimer();
  }
}
}
}
```

This code is giving me multipe errors, and the class is one of 3 I am using to create a spaceship that shoots lasers in java. What is the issue, and why won't this compile? I am really lost. Thanks!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: levelMenu, PLAY_PANEL, playMgr , where are these declared??

Answer (score 2):

I reformatted your code to make it easier to understand.  It would be beneficial to you if you used an integrated development environment (IDE) like Eclipse or Netbeans.

- levelMenu is not defined.
- PLAY_PANEL is not defined.
- playMgr is not defined.
- playPanel is not defined.

You have to define these fields in your class, and initialize these fields in a constructor or by setter methods.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class LevelSelectionMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        int levelNum = -1;
        boolean standard = true;
        if (event.getSource() == levelMenu.getProvidedList()) {
            levelMenu.clearCustomList();
            levelNum = levelMenu.getProvidedLevelNum();
        } else if (event.getSource() == levelMenu.getCustomList()) {
            levelMenu.clearProvidedList();
            levelNum = levelMenu.getCustomLevelNum();
            standard = false;
        }

        if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
            if (levelNum != -1) {
                changeContent(PLAY_PANEL, "startPlay");
                playMgr.initLevelForPlay(standard, levelNum);
                playPanel.startTimer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is levelMenu ? You use it without declare it first.